# Play frame work first use

Tags: playframework

I have downloaded the play-1.2.3.zip file, and could not find an exe file to run it, I'm using this framework for the first time, how can I run it.

I want to build simple public website using this tech for evaluation.

thanks,

Comment: Not to sound too harsh, but there is a documentation section in the Play site that explains how to use it with really good tutorials: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/home . You should read the documentation before asking for things like this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two programs that run play, depending on which platform you are on.

```
play.bat - for windows

play.sh - for linux
```

If you go to the directory where you installed Play, you can start a new project (lets assume called helloworld) by running

```
play new helloworld
```

and then

```
play run helloworld
```